# How to hide the navigation bar in LaTex beamer?

Tags: beamer

I am using LaTeX Beamer to prepare a presentation with lots of content. The navigation bar contains too many  subsections, so as to occupying large spaces. See following screenshot:
[image: navigation bar occupying large spaces]

I tried `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}`. This command could remove symbols on the bottom, but not the top navigation bar.

I also tried `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}`. However, this command only remove all contents in navigation bar, the navigation bar now look like this:
[image]

So how to hide the navigation bar? Or just hide the subsection part (right half)?

Edited: I give a short but complete example of LaTeX codes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  %\setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \usecolortheme{seahorse}
  %\usecolortheme{rose}
  \usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structuresmallcapsserif}
  \usefonttheme[onlysmall]{structurebold}
}

\newcommand*\oldmacro{}
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle % save previous definition
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{
\oldmacro \hfill  \leftskip=.3cm
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

%   if do not use navigation symbols (on the bottom), uncomment this
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%\setbeamertemplate{headline}
%{%
%\begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
%\vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
%\end{beamercolorbox}%
%}

\title{C++}

\author{Author}

\date{\today}

%\AtBeginSection[] %
%{
%  \begin{frame}<beamer>
%    \frametitle{Outline}
%    \tableofcontents[currentsection,subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]
%  \end{frame}
%}

\AtBeginSubsection[] %
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide]
    %\tableofcontents[currentsubsection,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide]
  \end{frame}
}

% If you wish to uncover everything in a step-wise fashion, uncomment
% the following command:
%\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  %\tableofcontents[pausesections,subsectionstyle=hide]
  \tableofcontents[currentsection,sectionstyle=show,subsectionstyle=hide]
  % You might wish to add the option [pausesections]
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   main


\section{STL}

\subsection{vector}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{STL} %
\begin{itemize}
\item STL.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsection{list}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{STL} %
\begin{itemize}
\item STL.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsection{stack}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{STL} %
\begin{itemize}
\item STL.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsection{queue}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{STL} %
\begin{itemize}
\item STL.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}




\subsection{map}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{STL} %
\begin{itemize}
\item STL.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\subsection{set}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{STL} %
\begin{itemize}
\item STL.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\subsection{iterator}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{STL} %
\begin{itemize}
\item STL.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would help if you could include a stripped-down version of your source code so we can see what beamer themes you're using.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your specific question, but: I assume that you've explored the possibility of using other themes? They don't all have navigation bars. Alternatively, if there's something you want in that particular theme, I wonder if it would be easier to change a nav-bar-less theme to do what you want. The main documentation file describes the standard themes, and there are others available on the web.

Comment: Thanks Matthew and Mars. I edited my post and add a shortened version of my source code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Warsaw` theme loads `shadow` outer theme which loads `split` outer theme. You can use `compress` option to flat navigation top bar. This way all sections and subsections will appear in a horizontal list instead of vertical.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
```

it's all you need.

If you don't want any `headline` would be better to use some other theme like `Pittsburg`, `Rochester` or `Madrid`, but you can still use `Warsaw` and suppress headline with

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, @Ignasi. Although it is not exactly what I want, I think the horizontal style is good enough. Thanks again.

Comment: @YunHuang: Ups! I misread your question. I've updated my answer, hope it's better now.